# I need to parse the GSUB and GPOS tables in an OpenType file. Is there any software available that does that?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, fonts, opentype

I need to inspect the binary content of the GSUB and GPOS tables in an OpenType font file in a more human-friendly way. Is there any software available that does that ?

Comment: [LuaTeX](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Explore_the_table_obtained_from_a_TrueType_font) allows you to do that, but I am not sure it will fit in your use case.

Comment: What do you mean by "to fit in your use case" ? I read the link you provided, but it doesn't seem to show the GPOS and GSUB tables.

Comment: Speaking of your use case, would you please expand on that a bit more? Do you just want to see the GSUB and GPOS tables in a more friendly way? Do you need to edit the tables? Do you need to do font rendering/layout using the GSUB and GPOS? Something else?

Comment: @djangodude I just need to see the tables. Actually I'm already parsing the tables manually, with the VS binary editor, as you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601120/ligature-substitution-in-opentype-file-doesnt-show-up-in-word-2010

Comment: I guess my answer maybe help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779107/convert-cff-fonts-into-opentype-fonts-programatically/10596106#10596106

Answer (score 3):

[fonttools/TTX](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) may do what you want. It is a Python-based font manipulation library. The TTX component can dump a font (TTF or OTF) to XML, allowing you to view the GSUB and GPOS (and many other tables) in an abstract way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python. This library, I suppose it doesn't work in C++, or it does ?

Comment: Just wanted to say you're a life saver @djangodude