# Compiling FreeType 2.6.3 on Windows to .dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, freetype2

I've read [Compiling FreeType to DLL (as opposed to static library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207176/compiling-freetype-to-dll-as-opposed-to-static-library). But in my ftoption.h isn't FT_BASE macro. There are only `FT_EXPORT` and `FT_EXPORT_DEF`. What values must they have?

Answer (score 2):

It says right there in comments under the answer you're citing.

> There should be a third `#define` in `ftoption.h` if you want to export everything: `#define FT_EXPORT_DEF(x) __declspec(dllexport) x`. http://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont/issues/24 – [Robert Rouhani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1122135/robert-rouhani) Jul 15 '13 at 20:32

<sup>[Compiling FreeType to DLL (as opposed to static library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207176/compiling-freetype-to-dll-as-opposed-to-static-library#comment25726967_7387618)</sup>

It would have been nice if Robert had edited this information into the answer. If you find that it works for you, you could consider doing so yourself so that others may benefit.