# Is there a -rdynamic equivalent to build dll with Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

In a DLL (linked at runtime) I need to call functions statically linked in my application.

I achieved to do this on the Linux side linking the application with the `-rdynamic` gcc option, but with Visual Studio I can't find a way to export all non-static symbols to dynamic libraries and to link the DLL without `unresolved symbol` errors.

- I don't really want to convert all my application in multiple DLLs and adding handy macros to handle the `_declspec(dllimport)`/`_declspec(dllexport)` properly.
- I neither don't want to pass all my API to DLLs by function pointers.

Is there a better way to work around this issue?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a non-kludgy way to do what you're looking for.  See this old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225432/export-all-symbols-when-creating-a-dll  But maybe someone has come up with a better technique in the few years since those answers...

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yep I already found this one, but obviously it seems even more complicated to set up a .def file