# visual studio project export list of dll-functions (signatures)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllexport

Is there some way/tool to create a list of all functions (with arguments) that have the directive `__declspec (dllexport)` in visual studio?

I could of course create script to parse all header/cpp files from a project - however it feels like creating the full C preprocessor to also check `#define` etc. Is there somewhere in visual studio a "hidden" method to create a plain text file with all FULL function signatures of exported functions in a dll?

Should I parse the .lib file created with the dll? - How? - Please note that I am looking for the **full** function signature, so including argumenttypes & namespaces etc.

Comment: instead of creating your own preprocessor, you could easily just use one like MCPP which is available on SF.net and compiles on Windows. There are also simplified modules for Perl and Python that provide *some* preprocessing capabilities, but not all the bells and whistles.

Comment: Yes, it's possible with newest version of the CMake. Look at my answer for clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32284832/3001953

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DependencyWalker tool, it's an old tool that used to be released with Visual Studio. You can download it from http://www.dependencywalker.com/.

Open your DLL, select all the function names, copy and paste it in your text file.

Comment: Yes, I know that tool, however it "loses" the full function signature - as it only shows the function names, not arguments & argument types.

Comment: @paul23: actually it *does* show these, *if* that information is available due to the mangled naming of the exports. If it isn't, the PDBs are your only method and there are APIs to access that information.