# How to make visual studio compile exports for C DLL the way MinGW does

Tags: c, dll, visual-studio-2013, dllexport

I have compiled a C DLL with MinGW and it made exports for everything I need without me specifying `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Visual Studio 2013 (in "compile as C" mode) produced a DLL without any exports.
Is there a VS C++ project setting I am missing that can do this kind of magic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225432/export-all-symbols-when-creating-a-dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225432/export-all-symbols-when-creating-a-dll).

Comment: Yes, it's possible with newest version of the CMake. Look at my answer for clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32284832/3001953