# Proper way to link static libraries with dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, declspec

My project builds through few static libraries which should linked to main dll library gain one single dll as a result.

Using `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute does not lead to appearance of specified functions of static libraries to dll, libraries not linked with dll at all.

Then I tried to build each library as shared for getting proper names of exported functions and created .def file based on them. Using .def file leaded to result.

1. Should `__declspec(dllexport)` and `.def-file` act equally in my case?
2. Is it possible to generate a .def file from sources? Since I have C++ code I'm not able to write .def file by myself because of mangling and presence classes in API, the approach described above with temporary generated dlls is inconsistent for production.

#### Update

I'd like to explain in detail about the structure of my project. The solution consists of a few projects (modules).

```
+ 
|    
+-+ static_lib1                                          
|       +                                                
|       +--+ src                                         
|                                                        
+-+ static_lib2                                          
|       +                                                
|       +--+ src                                         
|                                                        
+-+ dynamic_lib (linked with static_lib1 and static_lib2)
        +                                                
        +--+ src
```

Each sub-project weakly depends on others, let's assume they are not connected for clearness. Each module has own public interface. I want to have all modules as single dynamic library so my artifact is `dynamic_lib.dll`, but in fact static libraries are not linked with it.

Comment: Question: you said `[...] libraries not linked with dll at all`. Did you get an error in `dynamic_lib` or *another project*, that is **using** dynamic_lib? Was this error an `unresolved external [...]`?

Comment: `unresolved external`  when trying to use dll library in an external prodjects

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Static libraries should not contain any `__declspec` or `__attribute((dll...))` things. They are nothing more than multiple object files (usually `*.obj` or `*.o`), composed into one, single file.

All you need to do in order to use such library (either in `.exe` or `.dll`) is to include proper headers and link them - with Visual Studio it's pretty easy.

First of all, you need to know **1)** where your static libraries are placed and **2)** their exact names. Go to project properties and then `General`. `Target name` contains name for the output file, while `Output directory` indicates in which folder your `.lib` will be placed.

***Note:*** This path may be different for every project! For multi-project solution, I always set this to a common path to avoid configuration problems.

Now, go to properties of project, that will consume this library (link with it). Go to `Linker` -> `Input` and then add name of your `.lib` to `Additional dependencies` (entries are separated with semicolon):

[image: Linker input]

You need to add all libraries you want have linked in. Also, folder, in which these libraries are placed, must added to `Linker` -> `General` -> `Additional library directories`. If all `.lib`s are placed in the same place - good, otherwise copy them into shared location or add multiple entries to `Additional library directories` list.

And the last thing - remember, that you also need to include headers with declarations of functions and objects, that you want to use. Basic thing, I know, but has to be mentioned.

---

**UPDATE**

> unresolved external when trying to use dll library in an external prodjects

Your problem is **not** related to linking at all. The thing is, that you misunderstood what, linking a static library **exactly does**.

I am guessing, that functions reported as *unresolved* are not used by your `DLL`, right? But you expect them to be inside it, right?

When your `DLL` refers to an external content (like function or variable), it is resolved at linking time - together with all dependencies. **But that's all**. If your static library has a function named `print_sample_string()`, **but your `DLL` does not use it**, it won't be attached to `DLL` image. Think about this carefully - why should it be?

Even more - functions, that are not `dllexport`ed explicitly won't be visible anyway. Functions have by default external storage - so basically, they are private `DLL`'s content.

So to answer your question directly - if you need to use functions/variables from `static_lib1.lib`, attach it to client application - just like you are attaching it now to `dynamic_lib`. There is no other way. **(*)**

---

**(*)** Truly speaking - there is. You can create intermediate function in `DLL`, that is exported and call desired function inside:

**Somewhere in `dynamic_lib`:**

```
DLL_EXP_IMP long CallFunctionFromA_Lib()
{
     return some_function(); //this function is from static_lib1.lib
}
```

**Somewhere in `.exe`:**

```
long result = CallFunctionFromA_Lib(); //internally this will call function from static_lib1.lib
```

I can't imagine, however, why would you want to do this and not simply link `A.lib` and use it directly.

Comment: Thank you! But I have the same configuration. My problem is libraries are not use each other code, each library is separate module use its own public interface thus linker ignores others static libraries except main one

Comment: Update question with exact information about what libraries do you have, which one do you want use others (and which) and what is the error you get. I don't understand what does `linker ignores others static libraries except main one` mean.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140321-00/?p=1433) Raymond Chan explains this behavior and the best solution is really just to use def file. As for how to generate it automatically for static a library - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/731767/4074081) discussion looks like a good starting point.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits (Link works now)