# Error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\MyProjectLib.lib'

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt` file to generate my project based on Qt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(MyProject)

find_package(Qt5Widgets)

set(MyProjectLib_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.cpp)
set(MyProjectLib_hdr ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.h)
set(MyProjectLib_ui  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.ui)
set(MyProjectBin_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

qt5_wrap_cpp(MyProjectLib_hdr_moc ${MyProjectLib_hdr})
qt5_wrap_ui (MyProjectLib_ui_moc  ${MyProjectLib_ui})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

add_library(MyProjectLib SHARED 
    ${MyProjectLib_src}
    ${MyProjectLib_hdr_moc}
    ${MyProjectLib_ui_moc}
)
target_link_libraries(MyProjectLib Qt5::Widgets)

add_executable(MyProject ${MyProjectBin_src})
target_link_libraries(MyProject MyProjectLib)
```

When I try to compile the generated project, I got the following error:

> error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\MyProjectLib.lib'

The corresponding directory `Debug` contains:

```
MyPtojectLib.dll
MyProjectLib.ilk
MyProjectLib.pdb
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You declared `MyProjectLib` as a shared library, so unless you exported all or part of the symbols of the library, you will only have a `.dll` designed to be loaded at runtime, and no `.lib` to link against at compile time as you're trying to do.

A quick solution may be to declare `MyProjectLib` as a static library:

```
add_library(MyProjectLib STATIC ...)
```

Another option could be to use "new" cmake features to export all symbols (see [this article](https://blog.kitware.com/create-dlls-on-windows-without-declspec-using-new-cmake-export-all-feature/)):

```
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
```

You can also use the "traditional" way by explicitly declaring the symbols to be exported, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32284832/6612932) (the long answer). You will first need to declare some API macro somewhere in your code:

```
#ifdef MyProjectLib_EXPORTS
#define MyProjectLib_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MyProjectLib_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Note that `MyProjectLib_EXPORTS` is automatically generated by cmake for shared libraries: you don't need to care about this. Then for each of your class in your code, use the macro in the declaration:

```
class MyProjectLib_API MyClass { /* ... */ };
```

`MyClass` will be an exported symbol when compiling `MyProjectLib` because `MyProjectLib_EXPORTS` will be defined, and MyProjectLib_API will expand to `__declspec(dllexport)`. So it will be exported in a `.lib` file.

It will be an imported symbol when linking against `MyProjectLib` because `MyProjectLib_EXPORTS` will be undefined, and `MyProjectLib_API` will expand to `__declspec(dllimport)`.

---

You may also improve your cmake file like this:

```
qt5_wrap_cpp(MyProjectLib_hdr_moc ${MyProjectLib_hdr})
qt5_wrap_ui (MyProjectLib_ui_moc  ${MyProjectLib_ui})
```

You may use `AUTOMOC` and `AUTOUIC` instead to let cmake automatically handle the call to Qt's utilities.

```
include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories (${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
```

`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` is an include directory by default, and I can't see why you need to add `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` here: just remove these lines.

Once cleaned, your cmake file may become something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets)

set(MyProjectLib_src
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.ui
)

add_library(MyProjectLib STATIC
    ${MyProjectLib_src}
)
target_link_libraries(MyProjectLib Qt5::Widgets)

set(MyProjectBin_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

add_executable(MyProject
    ${MyProjectBin_src}
)
target_link_libraries (MyProject MyProjectLib)
```

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: Make sure you have source files, not just headers!

For web searchers who arrive here and may not have the OP's problem, I just encountered a very similar linking error that occurred because I had split libraries and left one of them without any source files, a header-only library:

```
add_library(hsm STATIC
  StateAbstract.hpp        # header-only
  StateMachineAbstract.hpp # header-only
  StateMachineBase.hpp     # header-only
)
```

My fix was to insert a cpp file pending restoration of class implementation files:

```
add_library(hsm STATIC
  Placeholder.cpp # this file causes hsm.lib to get generated on Windows
  StateAbstract.hpp        # header-only
  StateMachineAbstract.hpp # header-only
  StateMachineBase.hpp     # header-only
)
```

This may seem like it would be obvious, but I'm doing Linux/QNX development on this project and gcc creates a nearly empty library:

```
$ wc -c build/lib/libhsm.a 
8 build/lib/libhsm.a
$ strings build/lib/libhsm.a
!<arch>
```

That library links quite happily.  It was only later when the project was building the Windows version on a build server that I saw the error:

```
[4/6] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1413~1.261\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /lib /nologo /machine:x64 /out:build\lib\hsm.lib   && cd ."
[5/6] ...
[6/6]  cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe ... /out:build\gtest\hsm_test.exe ... build\lib\hsm.lib ...
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'build\lib\hsm.lib'
```

Since I saw the command to create the lib file in the build server output, I could not initially figure out why hsm.lib would not be there (and I cannot get on the build server).  Fortunately, as I read the other answer and triple-checked that it was statically linked, I noticed it was a header-only library - whew!  I feel lucky!