# What sources do I have to include in add_library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a given **project structure**

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   └── pixel_reader
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── src
│           ├── pixel_reader.cpp
│           ├── pixel_reader.h
│           ├── lodepng.cpp
│           └── lodepng.h
├── main.cpp
```

With the following CMakeLists

**./CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(pov_system VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(lib/pixel_reader)

add_executable(pov_system main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pov_system PRIVATE pixel_reader)
```

**./pixel_reader/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(
    pixel_reader SHARED
    src/pixel_reader.cpp
    src/pixel_reader.h
    src/lodepng.cpp
    src/lodepng.h
)

target_include_directories(pixel_reader PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

While building this CMake Project, I get the following error.

```
[build] 
[build]   pixel_reader.cpp
[build]   pixel_reader.vcxproj -> C:\Programming\GitHub\pov_system\build\lib\pixel_reader\Debug\pixel_reader.dll
[build]   main.cpp
[build] LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Datei "lib\pixel_reader\Debug\pixel_reader.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden. [C:\Programming\GitHub\pov_system\build\pov_system.vcxproj]
[build] Der Build wurde mit dem Exitcode 1 abgeschlossen.
```

**Question**

Am I adding and linking the library correctly?
What sources do I have to add as parameter to add_library? I have the feeling that this is my problem.

If you need additional informatons, please let me know.

Comment: You need to **export** at least one **symbol** from your library, otherwise linking with it has no sense and export file is not created. See more in the duplicate question.

Comment: Side note: When posting error messages, it's better if they're in English. I'm not sure how to do this from within VS (which you seem to be using?) but on the commandline on Linux just add `LANG=` in front of the cmake (or any, really) command.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40743080/260313. It looks you're only building a DLL but then you try to link against a LIB.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40743080/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40743080/487892) is a good answer. I recommend you study this even if you are not using Qt.