# How does GCC/Clang compilers decide the symbol type?

Tags: c++, static-linking

I have an issue with binary (already stripped) displaying symbols that leak a confidential information. When I look at binary, all symbols that are of concern are one of `T`, `D` or `S` types.

Now since binary is statically linked (using external static libs that use different namespace), I cannot help but wonder, why do those symbols are global and why ld/strip did not remove them from symbol table?

So there are somehow two related questions:

- How does compiler/linker decide which symbols are global?
- Is there a way to make sure that compiler/linker does not export those symbols?

Comment: *"is there a way to make sure that compiler/linker does not export those symbols?"* - which symbols?  Can you show example source code that demonstrates the problem?  Or explain what the symbols are in your project.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I wish I knew how to provide minimal example without posting here proprietary static libs etc. I guess more important is the first question in the post -- how does compiler/linker decide when those symbols should be global. I will amend to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you mean this  [Why is the new C++ visibility support so useful?](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and [Export all symbols when creating a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225432)

Comment: @t.niese in my case all libs are static. I actually do not create a lib. I am using vendor provided libs and link them. But somehow some of my methods appear as exported (methods that use those libs)