# Can you export all symbols by default on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, compilation

I learned recently that on Linux, all symbols of a library are exported by default, but on Windows, none are. It seems that for every symbol of a library you care about, you must do `__declspec(dllexport)` and pair it with a `__declspec(dllimport)` on the receiving end.

Doing this for every symbol sounds like a chore, and bloats the code, and hurts readability. Is it possible to just enable all symbols by default?

I have read [Export all symbols when creating a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225432/), but all of the answers there seem extremely laborious and hacky. I would like a linker flag or something of the sort, if it exists. The linked post was from over 10 years ago, so maybe things have improved since then?

Comment: Did you read this: [Export all symbols when creating a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225432/export-all-symbols-when-creating-a-dll) ?

Comment: Maybe edit your question to specify if you are using the Microsoft or GCC linker...

Comment: Why? Why on earth would you **ever** want that? *"maybe things ahve improved since then"* - having all symbols private by default is the correct solutions. There's no need to improve anything that's not broken.

Comment: Why would that be the correect solution? Neither clang nor gcc do this, Unix systems work just fine without this nonsense and it makes the programmer's life way more diffucult.

Comment: Exported symbols are the **public** interface. It would seem somewhat random to just have **everything** be part of the public interface. Why would that be desirable? Why would it be a good idea to inconvenience developers that cautiously design their interfaces?

Comment: Why would it incoinvenience the ones that want to put in the effort to select public and private symbols? If anything it inconveniences those that don;t care. For those that do care it's basically the same amount of work, make a macro at the start that is by default not exporting a symbol and is swithc to enable a symbol for the few desired public ones.

This works on Unix systems so tyhere is no argument to say it cannot be done that way.

Comment: *"This works on Unix systems so tyhere is no argument to say it cannot be done that way."* - Of course it **can** be done. Then again, Linux doesn't even have an API, so controlling a public API surface is not something that Linux developers are generally exposed to. You'll also observe that LTO makes a significant difference on Linux. On Windows, it usually doesn't. A corollary of the correct decision to have symbols private by default. *"it's basically the same amount of work"* - So then, why do you even care?